# Struts Jquery plugin - grid showing json data, grid is displayed within a modal dialog

Tags: json, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, struts2, modal-dialog

I have a jsp page (page1.jsp).  This page has a grid, the grid gets loaded using say action class A and on one of the grid columns I have a onclick open a dialog.  The dialog on open calls a different struts action class, say B.  This action class has a resulting page, page2.jsp.  This page also has a grid.  The problem i am having is the data is getting displayed in JSON format instead of on the grid.

I am not sure if the struts.xml has an issue or where the problem is.  I have inspected the JSON data in firebug and everything looks correct, the gridModel has data as expected, but the data is not showed on the grid, it is shown as JSON data on the modal dialog.

Using:  Struts  2.2.3, Struts-jquery-plugin version 3.3.1

Relevant Code:
page1.jsp

```
                                <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
                                function formatLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                        return "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:openDialog("+cellvalue+")'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
                                    }
                                function openDialog(fsNumber) {
                                        $("#sqv").load("<s:property value="testurl"/>?number="+number);
                                        $("#sqv").dialog('open');
                                    }
                                </SCRIPT>
                                <sjg:grid
                                    id="dataGrid"
                                    caption="States"
                                    hidegrid="false"
                                    dataType="json"
                                    href="%{remoteurl}"
                                    pager="false"
                                    altRows="true"
                                    gridModel="gridModel"
                                    rowNum="100000"
                                    rowTotal="100000"
                                    loadonce="true"
                                    width="940"
                                    tabindex="false"
                                    onSelectRowTopics="rowselect">
                                    <sjg:gridColumn name="st.fsNumber" index="st.fsNumber" title="FNS Number" formatter="formatfsNumberStars252Link" sortable="true" sorttype="integer" width="80"/>
                                    <sjg:gridColumn name="st.stName" index="st.stName" title="Store Name" sortable="true" width="210"/>
                                    <sjg:gridColumn name="st.stType.stTypeCode" index="st.stType.stTypeCode" title="Store Type" sortable="true" width="40"/>
                                    <sjg:gridColumn 
                                            name="st.fsNumber" 
                                            index="st.fsNumber" 
                                            title="Action" 
                                            formatter="formatLink" 
                                            sortable="false" 
                                            width="80"
                                    />
                                </sjg:grid>
                            </div>
```

Page2.jsp

```
                                <div id="idTwo">
                                    <s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonSQV"/>
                                    <sjg:grid
                                        id="dataGrid"
                                        caption="Activity"
                                        hidegrid="false"
                                        dataType="json"
                                        href="%{remoteurl}"
                                        pager="false"
                                        altRows="true"
                                        gridModel="gridModel"
                                        loadonce="true"
                                        rowNum="100000"
                                        rowTotal="100000"
                                        tabindex="true"
                                        width="940">
                                        <sjg:gridColumn name="reportTime" index="reportTime" title="Reporting Period" formatter="date" formatoptions="{srcformat: 'm/Y', newformat:'m/Y'}" sortable="true" sorttype="date" width="80"/>
                                        <sjg:gridColumn name="volume" index="volume" title="Dollar Volume" formatter="currency" formatoptions="{prefix: '$', thousandsSeparator:','}" sortable="true" sorttype="currency" width="140"/>
                                        <sjg:gridColumn name="summary" index="summary" title="ALERT Rank" formatter="number" sortable="true" sorttype="number" width="60"/>
                                    </sjg:grid>
                                </div>
                               <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {$('#dataGrid').attr('tabindex','800');});</script>
```

Corresponding Struts.xml

```
    <package name="blah" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">

    <action name="*ClassA" class="com.ads.snf.trelang.action.ClassA" method="{1}">
        <result name="input">/blah/page1.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/blah/page1.jsp</result>
        <result name="json" type="json"><param name="target">gridModel</param></result>
    </action>

    <action name="*SQV" class="com.ads.snf.trelang.action.ClassB" method="{1}">
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">executeStoreQuickView</param>
        </result>
        <result name="success"  type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">jsonStoreQuickView</param>
        </result>
        <result name="json" type="json"><param name="target">gridModel</param></result>
    </action>



</package>
```

Class B Action class:

```
public class ClassB extends BaseAction {

@Autowired
MRservice service;
private SQVResponse response;
private Integer number;
private Integer fromYear;
private Integer toYear;
private Integer toMonth;
private Integer fromMonth;
@HoldDataInSession
private String dateRangeFrom;
@HoldDataInSession
private String dateRangeTo;

//STRUTS2 JQUERY GRID STUFF
//get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum attribute in the grid
private Integer rows = 0;
//Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1.
private Integer page = 0;
// sorting order - asc or desc
private String sord;
// get index row - i.e. user click to sort.
private String sidx;
// Search Field
private String searchField;
// The Search String
private String searchString;
// he Search Operation ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']
private String searchOper;
// Your Total Pages
private Integer total = 0;
// All Record
private Integer records = 0;

@Override
public String input() {
    LoggingUtility.info("inside input method.", this.getClass().getName());
    String result = super.input();        
    getReport();
    return result;
}

public String execute() {
    //super.input();
     LoggingUtility.info("inside execute  method.", this.getClass().getName());
    return getReport();
}

public String json() {
    LoggingUtility.info("Entered json().", this.getClass().getName());
    String result = ERROR;
    //get response from session 
    if (this.getUserSessionDetails().getReportResponse() != null) {
        this.response = (SQVResponse) this.getUserSessionDetails().getReportResponse();
    }
    result = JSON;
    LoggingUtility.info("Exiting json().", this.getClass().getName());
    return result;

}

private String getReport() {

      HashMap<String, Object> map;
    LoggingUtility.info("Entering getReport", this.getClass().getName());
    String result = ERROR;
    try {



        if (response == null){
            response = new SQVResponse();
        }
        //response has data, and hence the response.getResultList..this has been verified in debug mode
        setGridModel(response.getResultList());
        if (LoggingUtility.getLogger().isInfoEnabled() && response.getResultList() != null) {
            int cnt = response.getResultList().size();
            LoggingUtility.info("MRservice.getReport returned the following number of results: " + cnt, this.getClass().getName());
        }
        if (this.response.getResultList().size() == 0) {
            addActionMessage(getText(UserInterfaceConstants.GENERAL_SEARCH_RESULT_MESSAGE_100));
        }
        this.getUserSessionDetails().setReportResponse(response);
        result = SUCCESS;
        //result = JSON;
    } catch (BaseSystemException e) {
        List<String> argList = new ArrayList<String>();
        argList.add(e.getExceptionId());
        addActionError(getText(e.getExceptionMessageCode(), argList));
        LoggingUtility.error("Error .", e, this.getClass().getName());
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        List<String> argList = new ArrayList<String>();
        UUID expId = UUID.randomUUID();
        argList.add(expId.toString());
        addActionError(getText(Constants.SYSTEM_EXCEPTION_200, argList));
        LoggingUtility.error("Exception ID: " + expId.toString() + "Error in getting Report Data.", e, this.getClass().getName());
    }

    return result;
}



public Integer getnumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setnumber(Integer number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public Integer getFromYear() {
    return fromYear;
}

public void setFromYear(Integer fromYear) {
    this.fromYear = fromYear;
}

public Integer getToYear() {
    return toYear;
}

public void setToYear(Integer toYear) {
    this.toYear = toYear;
}

public Integer getToMonth() {
    return toMonth;
}

public void setToMonth(Integer toMonth) {
    this.toMonth = toMonth;
}

public Integer getFromMonth() {
    return fromMonth;
}

public void setFromMonth(Integer fromMonth) {
    this.fromMonth = fromMonth;
}

public String getDateRangeFrom() {
    return dateRangeFrom;
}

public void setDateValueFrom(String dateValue) {
    this.dateRangeFrom = dateValue;
    if (!dateValue.isEmpty()) {
        String[] dateFrom = dateValue.split("/");
        this.fromMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateFrom[0]);
        this.fromYear = Integer.parseInt(dateFrom[1]);
    }
}

public void setDateValueTo(String dateValue) {
    this.dateRangeTo = dateValue;
    if (!dateValue.isEmpty()) {
        String[] dateTo = dateValue.split("/");
        toMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateTo[0]);
        toYear = Integer.parseInt(dateTo[1]);
    }

}

public void setDateRangeFrom(String dateRangeFrom) {
    this.dateRangeFrom = dateRangeFrom;
}

public String getDateRangeTo() {
    return dateRangeTo;
}

public void setDateRangeTo(String dateRangeTo) {
    this.dateRangeTo = dateRangeTo;
}

public Integer getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(Integer rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

public Integer getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public String getSord() {
    return sord;
}

public void setSord(String sord) {
    this.sord = sord;
}

public String getSidx() {
    return sidx;
}

public void setSidx(String sidx) {
    this.sidx = sidx;
}

public String getSearchField() {
    return searchField;
}

public void setSearchField(String searchField) {
    this.searchField = searchField;
}

public String getSearchString() {
    return searchString;
}

public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
    this.searchString = searchString;
}

public String getSearchOper() {
    return searchOper;
}

public void setSearchOper(String searchOper) {
    this.searchOper = searchOper;
}

public Integer getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public Integer getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(Integer records) {
    this.records = records;
}

public MRservice getService() {
    return service;
}

public void setService(MRservice service) {
    this.service = service;
}

public List<SQVBean> getGridModel() {
    return response.getResultList();
}

public void setGridModel(List<SQVBean> gridModel) {
    this.response.setResultList(gridModel);
}

public Integer getMenuIndex() {
    return menuIndex;
}



public String getPageType() {
    return getScreenId().substring(getScreenId().lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
}

public SQVResponse getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(SQVResponse response) {
    this.response = response;
}
```

}

Also, most of the code above is shown relevant to issue at hand.

Please help.  Hope I described the problem atleast.

Thank you,
John

Comment: The problem i am having is the data is getting displayed in JSON format instead of on the grid on page2.jsp                               `code`<div id="sample1">
         <s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonSL"/>
         <s:url id="testurl" action="executeSQV">
         </s:url>
         <sj:dialog
          id="sqv"
          title="Details"
          autoOpen="false"
          modal="true"
          width="800"
         >
         
         </sj:dialog>

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 action :

```
<action name="DisplayAction" class="com.ads.snf.trelang.action.ClassA" method="{1}">
    <result name="input">/blah/page1.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/blah/page1.jsp</result></action>

<action name="JsonAction" class="com.ads.snf.trelang.action.ClassA" method="{1}">
    <result type="json"></result></action>
```

And when you pass result param like gridModel, best way it's with root.

gridModel

But dont need to specify param if you set gridModel="gridModel", struts will read you json and found the gridModel list with no problem.

If you need more information about Struts2-jquery, I invite you to post on : https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr&fromgroups#!forum/struts2-jquery

Johannes will answer to anyquestion you have and others struts2-jquery users too. I hope this will work because I didn't look all the code but seems to be good.